# Undefined variable: produit (View: C:\laragon\www\AnnocesPFE\resources\views\produits\edit.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, edit

This is my edit view :

```
@extends('layouts.form')
@section('card')
 @if ($message1 = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
            <strong>{{$message1}}</strong>
        </div>
            @endif
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('produit.update', $produit->id)}}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
              @include('partials.form-group', [
                'title' => __('Description'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'description',
                'value' => $produit->description,
                'required' => true,
                ])

 @component('components.button')
                @lang('Modifier')
            @endcomponent
</form>
@endsection
```

This is my ProduitController :

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $produit=Produit::find($id);

        return view('produits.edit', compact('produits','id'));

    }


    public function update(Request $request,Produit $produit)
{
    $produit->update($request->all());
    $produit = Produit::find($id);
    $produit->save();
    return back()->with('success', __('Le produit a bien été changée !'));
}
```

im getting this error

> Undefined variable: produit (View: C:\laragon\www\AnnocesPFE\resources\views\produits\edit.blade.php)

Comment: `compact('produits')` isn't going to work when your variable name is **`$produit`**... Voting to close as typo; please refrain from answering.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function edit($id)
{
   $produit = Produit::find($id);
   // Fix typo 'produits' -> 'produit' 
   return view('produits.edit', compact('produit','id'));
}


public function update(Request $request,Produit $produit)
{
    $produit->update($request->all());
    $produit = Produit::find($id);
    $produit->save();
    // Passing data to view via with('product', $product) method  
    return back()->with('product', $product)->with('success', __('Le produit a bien été changée !'));
}
```

Comment: Done. Could you check ?